# how to fix the _replace method

Tags: python, class

```
class type_name:
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self._fields = fields
        self._mutable = False 
        self.a = self._fields[0]
        self.b = self._fields[1]
        self.c = self._fields[2]

    def _replace(self, **kargs):
        if self._mutable:
            for key, value in kargs.items():
                if key == 'a':
                    self.a = value
                if key == 'b':
                    self.b = value
                if key == 'c':
                    self.c = value
            return None
        else:
            A = self.a, B = self.b, C = self.c
            return self.type_name(**kargs)
```

the _replace method takes **kargs as input. the _replace method depends on the value stored in the instance name self._mutable.
if self.mutable == True, the instance namess of the object it is called on are changed and the method returns None So, if origin = Point(0,0) and we call origin._replace(y=5), then print(origin) would display as Point(x=0,y=5) because origin is mutated.

If self.mutable == False, it returns a new object of the same class, whose instance name's values are the same, except for those specified in kargs. So, if origin = Point(0,0) and we call new_origin = origin._replace(y=5), then print(origin,new_origin) would display as Point(x=0,y=0) Point(x=0,y=5) because origin is not mutated

I am not sure what is wrong with my function _replace, can someone help me to fix it? thanks

Comment: Please format the body of text properly using `` like  `<some code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `__init__()` doesn't take keyword arguments, only a `list` called `fields`. You either need to change your `__init__()` method or map the `kwargs` to a `list`:

```
class type_name:
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self._fields = fields
        self._mutable = False 
        self.a = self._fields[0]
        self.b = self._fields[1]
        self.c = self._fields[2]

    def _replace(self, **kwargs):
        if not self._mutable:
            return type_name([kwargs[c] for c in 'abc'])
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'a':
                self.a = value
            if key == 'b':
                self.b = value
            if key == 'c':
                self.c = value
        return None

a = type_name([1,2,3])
b = a._replace(a=3, b=2, c=1)
b.a
# 3
```

To be honest, I don't like this overloaded use of `_replace()`. Create 2 different methods.

Comment: I would reconsider the whole approach. there should be an abstract base class that has either a mutable or immutable implementation - mixing both approaches from the beginning seems like poor design.